# Should I glue or nail hardwood flooring in several widths up to 6 inches?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I'm preparing to install 3/4 inch solid white oak in a bedroom using 3-1/4, 4 and 6 inch width boards. I'll be using a alternating pattern of 3-1/4, 4, 6, 3-1/4, 4 and 6.

I'm told if a board is over 5 inches wide, gluing the boards is the best method. However, because only one of the boards is 6 inches, I'm wondering if gluing is necessary.

My inclination is staple the flooring to felt, leavings a 1/4 inch gap between the sheets where I would apply a flooring adhesive.

What would you do?

FYI: I live in CT, where we get all four seasons of humid summers and dry winters. This will be installed in a child's 16 x 12 bedroom above a garage.

Thanks

Comment: Is this tongue and groove hardwood?

Comment: What is the material of the subfloor?

Comment: I don't understand the felt and the gap. How does one staple floor boards to felt, and what (and where) is the gap?

Comment: Evil Greebo...yes it is tongue and grove hardwood.

Comment: isherwood...imagine laying out your felt and instead of a 4 inch over lap, there's a 1/4 gap used to apply an adhesive.

Comment: Jim Stewart...subfloor is plywood

Comment: Gluing flooring down on a 1/4" strip would be like using staples to assemble a car. It'll look fine until you try and use it. :P

Comment: Isherwood…sorry…the method uses staples/nails every 6 to 8 inches and a glue bead

Answer (score 1):

I like installing solid wood on sleepers, but it requires an extra 3/4” depth for the floor installation.

I’d also acclimate the wood to the room for a couple weeks prior to installation. To me, acclimation means separating the boards and spreading them out on the floor...do not leave them bundled.

Then, I like nailing the boards to the sleepers through the tongue side at about 12” - 16” oc. Stagger the sleepers under the boards and leave about 1/2” air gap at the edges. (I’ve installed boards like this in gymnasiums, but we use thicker boards, thicker sleepers and we leave a 2” gap at the edges. )

One trick to make sure the tongue and groove is milled properly is to hold one board vertically and jam another into the t&g edge. It should fit snug. If it holds and doesn’t slip out, then it’s fine. If not, the boards will wiggle and creak when walked on. Try lots of boards using both edges.

Oh, we stain prior to installation, but seal after.

Oh, for best results, install in the dry season...for obvious reasons.

Comment: What are the advantages of laying on sleepers vs a good quality sub-floor? What are the dimensions of the sleepers? species of wood? Do you put felt on the sleepers?

Comment: @JimStewart I follow the National Wood Flooring Association (NWFA) guidelines. It all varies based on species, etc., but the felt goes under the sleepers. DIYers use nails, which are fine for small installations, but power staplers are a must for large jobs.

Comment: I should not comment on this because others know so much more.

Comment: @JimStewart Oh, I don’t know anything. I just like to argue.

Comment: @JimStewart Most people don’t want to argue/discuss issues. They just make a statement and then that’s the end of it...

Answer (score 0):

Just nail it and forget about glue.

You mention felt. If you are going to put down a layer of felt, you could not glue it. Would the felt be present to prevent squeaks? Or would the felt be designed to prevent liquid spills from penetrating through to the subfloor?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to minimize the potential for squeaks. 

Also, because the floor is above a garage that is much more humid in the summer than the rest of the house, my fear is humidity will get into the space between the floor (there is insulation), penetrate the subfloor and get absorbed into the hardwood resulting in cupping.

Is that a concern I need to take into account?

Comment: Jim, there seems to be debate between staples or nails...thoughts?

Comment: I think good quality primer and paint on the ceiling of the garage would prevent moisture from penetrating. (I assume that the garage is completely finished with drywall)  But I am not experienced in this and would be surmising.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I may be over thinking this and worring about something i shouldn't. The garage is finished. Do you have a preference for staples or nails?

Comment: What kind of nails? There are special cleat nails for hardwood flooring. The same automatic nailer will drive staples or these cleat nails. I hear that staples are more commonly used. https://blog.cityfloorsupply.com/cleats-vs-staples-debate/

Comment: I nail and have never glued depending on the T&G thickness and location I do run strips (thin T&G felt then flooring) when I use strips they are usually much thicker than 1/4". I have seen smaller areas done with both but have seen glued jobs exhibit more buckling than nailed.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the show but...

Any board 4" or wider is prone to cupping. That's why they recommend gluing and nailing.

As for staples or cleats ( L nails )... Cleats are the way to go. Yes pneumatic tools are easier to use and most shoot staples. The problem with pneumatic nailers is you CANNOT get as tight a floor as with a manual nailer. Bear in mind too, that I was in the hardwood business BEFORE any of the new tools were brought in to the picture.

Installing over sleepers on a wood subfloor is a waste of time and money. I'm not condemning anyone else's answers here, just offering my 2 cents based off of my 12 years experience in the hardwood flooring industry.